# How do I remove GNOME extensions?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweak-tool

Ubuntu 17.10 (xorg), gnome 3.26.2, tweak tool installed.  I have installed the `gnome-shell-extensions`, `chrome-gnome-shell`, and the web browser add-on `gnome-shell-integration`.

In the tweak tool, under extensions, I see all the extensions I downloaded and installed from https://extensions.gnome.org.

1. I do not see any buttons (a red "X") next to each extension within the tweak tool in order to remove the individual extension.  Is that by design?  Is the only way to remove an extension is by going to https://extensions.gnome.org via a web browser?
2. I also do not see within the tweak tool a button or hyperlink that will open https://extensions.gnome.org.  Is that also by design?

Answer (score 4):

It seems the option to uninstall extensions from GNOME Tweaks is removed.

You may simply remove the folder associated to a particular extension from `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` in order to uninstall the extension.

Comment: Thank you pomsky.  However.....  I have more extensions listed in the Tweak tool than there are folders in that location.  Example:  I have an extension called Alternatetab showing up in the Tweak Tool Extensions (I have it turned off).  Yet, there is no folder for it in ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions.

Comment: @dln949 Those are system extensions, installed by default. You'll find them in `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` (I would not recommend deleting these system folders, simply deactivate the ones you don't need).

Comment: The extensions still show in the Tweak Tool after I removed their folders. Do I need to reboot?

Answer (score 0):

What works for me: I am unable to remove several "mock" extensions and others which show error in Gnome Tweaks and in the Ubuntu Store.  As well, they do not show a respective folder in home/share/gnome-shell/extensions

However, in Firefox Quantum 68 after installing the Add-On I am able to remove these extensions.  Chrome did not do the job for me...

Distro: Ubuntu 19.04 Gnome 3.32

Answer (score 0):

I had some mock extensions installed which I couldn't remove through the browser.  The solution was to open a terminal and move them.. they were located in

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
```

Move the folder to another location then log out and log in again to see the update.